# Merge / burninate multiple Google APIs related tags

Tags: support, tags, retag-request

Google provides the [Business Profile APIs](https://developers.google.com/my-business/ref_overview), which includes the [Google My Business API](https://developers.google.com/my-business/reference/rest).

Here are the tags I could find on Stack Overflow:

- [google-business-profile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-business-profile)
- [google-business-profile-api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-business-profile-api)
- [google-business](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-business)
- [google-my-business](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-my-business)
- [google-my-business-api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-my-business-api)

I would suggest that we either

- merge all these tags into [google-business-profile-api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-business-profile-api) or
- merge the [google-business-profile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-business-profile) tag into [google-business-profile-api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-business-profile-api) and [google-business](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-business) and [google-my-business](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-my-business) tags into [google-my-business-api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-my-business-api)